# hamburgler.js not working closing on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use hamburgler.js for a website via
http://codepen.io/Johnm__/pen/eNgXZW. everything works great on desktop but when I view it on my mobile, I can click the menu and the menu will pop up. but when i try to click a link it will not do nothing or if i click the menu it will not exit. Here is my full js with other functions but the first 2 are for the menu that im having trouble with :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function e() {
    $("body").on("touchstart", function(e) {
        $("body").hasClass("noscroll") && e.preventDefault()
    })
}
$(document).foundation(), e(), $(".icon").click(function() {
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500), $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate"), $("body").toggleClass("noscroll"), $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate"), $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate")
}), $(".mobilenav a").click(function() {
    $(".mobilenav").fadeOut(500), $(".top-menu").removeClass("top-animate"), $("body").removeClass("noscroll"), $(".mid-menu").removeClass("mid-animate"), $(".bottom-menu").removeClass("bottom-animate")
}), $(".viewport").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children("a").children("img").animate({
        height: "300",
        left: "0",
        top: "0",
        width: "500"
    }, 100), $(this).children("a").children("span").fadeIn(200)
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children("a").children("img").animate({
        height: "300",
        left: "0",
        top: "0",
        width: "500"
    }, 100), $(this).children("a").children("span").fadeOut(200)
}), $(".skillbar").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".skillbar-bar").animate({
        width: jQuery(this).attr("data-percent")
    }, 2e3)
}), $.fn.lbyl = function(e) {
    {
        var n = $.extend({
                content: "",
                speed: 10,
                type: "fade",
                fadeSpeed: 500,
                finished: function() {}
            }, e),
            t = $(this),
            i = [],
            o = n.content;
        $(this).length
    }
    t.empty(), t.attr("data-time", o.length * n.speed);
    for (var a = 0; a < o.length; a++) i.push(o[a]);
    $.each(i, function(e, i) {
        t.append('<span style="display: none;">' + i + "</span>"), setTimeout(function() {
            "show" == n.type ? t.find("span:eq(" + e + ")").show() : "fade" == n.type && t.find("span:eq(" + e + ")").fadeIn(n.fadeSpeed)
        }, e * n.speed)
    }), setTimeout(function() {
        n.finished()
    }, o.length * n.speed)
}, $(".example-1").lbyl({
    content: "..."
}), $(".example-2").lbyl({
    content: "..."
})
```

});

How can i make it so it will work for mobile as well as desktop? im not sure which jquery method is needed for this to happen. Any help to point me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend this one instead - looks far simpler http://www.internetkultur.at/simple-hamburger-drop-down-menu-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: Just tried it but nothing.

Comment: I wanted to keep the transparent overlay it gives me but i will look into the link you sent. thank you.

Comment: no problem just trying to help

Comment: I just used a different one and working like a charm. Thanks for your reply! =)

Comment: great! please click on my name and vote up one one of my answers! when you have 15 reputation that is..

Answer (score 0):

in your hamburgler.js it's probably the noscroll class thats appended to the body tag... try getting rid of the class and see if its still broken

```
if ($('body').hasClass('noscroll')) {
```

:P